# Wordpress wp_redirect CORS Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payu

I have troubles trying to do a redirection to a external URL using wp_redirect() method in a wordpress checkout plugin to integrate woocommerce checkout with PayU Latam php SDK.

It always throw a CORS issue with this message

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://lorem.ipsum.dolor.com.co/xxxxxxxxxxxx/StartTransaction.htm?enc=xxxxxxxx%xxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxx. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Also the redirection response code is **200** but with **OPTIONS** method

This is the code that I`m using

```
$response = PayUPayments::doAuthorizationAndCapture($parameters);
if ($response) {
if ($response->transactionResponse->state)
    if ($response->transactionResponse->state == "PENDING") {
        $response->transactionResponse->pendingReason;
        $response->transactionResponse->extraParameters->BANK_URL;
    }
$response->transactionResponse->responseCode;

$this->redirectURL = $response->transactionResponse->extraParameters->BANK_URL;
wp_redirect($this->redirectURL);
exit;
}
```

Someone can show me what i missing please??? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Put below code in your .htacess :

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay Shah... unfortunately with this setting the request generated by this line $response = PayUPayments::doAuthorizationAndCapture($parameters); dont have any response and the redirect is not triggered